# VBA Loop - Check Bank Holiday - if it is then restart the loop from scratch

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

I have a date that I then want to compare to a list of Bank Holidays, if the date is in the list then minus 1 day from the date and re-check the date from the start of the list.

I have this so far:

```
For Each bhday In Sheets("testsheet").Range("$A$2:$A$" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

If testday= bankhol Then
tesday= DateAdd("d", -1, testday)
'RESTART THE LOOP AND CHECKS
Else

'IS NOT A BANK HOL CONTINUE CHECK

End If
Next bhday
```

Obviously this doesnt start the loop at the first value, how do i go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the holidays database in a sheet, then get your date and use `workbookfunction.match()` surround with Error handler. Something like:

```
On Error Resume Next
value = WorksheetFunction.Match(testday, Sheets("BD").[A:B], 0)
On Error GoTo 0
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe it's easier if you put a formula in a cell. Example:

```
Set HelpCell = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 1)
With HelpCell
  .Formula = "=MATCH(" & bhday & ",Holiday_BD!A:A,0)"
  testDay = .Value
  .ClearContents
End With
```

or Just:

```
With Range("A1")
  .Formula = "=MATCH(" & bhday & ",Holiday_BD!A:A,0)"
  testDay = .Value
  .ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: would you be able to give an example of this? I take it if it Errors this is where the value is not found in the list?

Comment: Sorry @user3219693. `Match()` search for a value in selected range 2nd parameters. If the value is not found it returns an error. Thats why I surround it with error Hander.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason why you cannot use the `WORKDAY()` excel function, then that would probably be an easier way to do it.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/workday-HP005209339.aspx

You can insert your date in a cell, then have a list of holidays. Then just use the workday function. Set 1 as the "days" parameter and if its a Holiday (or a weekend, which is useful too in many instances), then it will show a different result (need to tweak slightly to have it register the date before as "1" will be the first date AFTER your input date)